# Borel-Cantelli lemma and countable intersection manipulation at the end of a complicated problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, analysis, predicate-logic, borel-cantelli-lemmas

I am struggling to understand how to apply Borel-Cantelli lemma at the end of a complicated problem.
This is the problem:
[image]

[image]
[image]

The expressions I am having trouble with are the last two probability expressions which are highlighted.

**1) For the first one I am trying to use the definition of limsup of events.**

Defining $A_n= \{|S_n|\ge\varepsilon n^p \}$ The fact that the $\sum_n P\{|S_n|\ge\varepsilon n^p \}< \infty$ tells me that by the Borel Cantelli lemma, $P(\limsup A_n)=0$ and so $P((\limsup A_n )^C)=1$

Then if $x \in (\limsup A_n)^C= (\cap_{n\ge 1}\cup_{k\ge n} A_k)^C=\cup_{n\ge 1}\cap_{k\ge n} A_k^c$ it means that

$\exists n_0: \forall k\ge n_0, x \in A_k^C=\{\frac{S_k}{k^p}<\varepsilon\}$

or changing variables

$\exists n_0: \forall n\ge n_0, x \in A_n^C=\{\frac{S_n}{n^p}<\varepsilon\}$

This proves that for large enough n : $(\limsup A_n)^C \subseteq A_n^C=\{\frac{S_n}{n^p}<\varepsilon\}$

Can the the opposite inclusion be proven? How do I get to book's expression? Notice that in the book  there is a $"\le \varepsilon"$ instead  and there is an "$\implies$ " that I don't get. Then I am thinking about having to use some logic manipulation here $(p\implies q)\equiv \lnot p \vee q$ or it looks like " $\forall n\ge n_0 , |S_n/n^p|<\varepsilon$" is logically equivalent to  "$n \ge n_0 \implies |S_n/n^p|<\varepsilon"$ which read out loud makes sense but it would be nice to have a rigorous proof

**2)For the second one I am clueless. Can you explain in detail how is that countable intersection carried out to yield that expression?**

Comment: I think you are overcomplicating it. For any sequence in a metric space, $x_n \to x_\infty$ if and only if for every $\epsilon>0$ one has $d(x_n,x_\infty)<\epsilon$ all but finitely often. Thus to get almost sure convergence, one would like to assert $$P\left(\bigcap_{\epsilon >0} \{|X_n-X_\infty|>\epsilon\text{ i.o.}\}\right) = 0$$. This is done by first reducing the intersection to a countable one. Next, Borel-Cantelli gives you for any fixed $\epsilon>0$ that $P(|X_n-X_\infty|>\epsilon\text{ i.o}) = 0$. Applying continuity of measure gives you it for all $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Most of the time, one does not think of $\limsup A_n = \bigcap_{n\geq 1}\bigcup_{k\geq n}A_k$, but rather $\limsup A_n = A_n\text{ i.o.}$ Same for $\liminf A_n = A_n\text{ all but finitely often}$

Comment: @AndrewZhang  Is one supposed to be able to automatically write $P(\exists n_0: n\ge n_0 \implies |Sn/n^P|\le \varepsilon)=1$  from the $i.o$ meaning?

Comment: What has been shown is that $P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon \text{ i.o.}) = 0$. In other words, $P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon \text{ a.b.f.o}) = 1$, which is what the author has written.

Comment: @AndrewZhang  how do I link the probability of the intersection with the single probabilities given by Borel cantelly? the event's are not disjoint. And how do you apply "continuity of measures" ?

Comment: $P(\lim A_n) = \lim P(A_n)$ if the $A_n$ are decreasing.

Comment: Come to think of it, I may have wrote too quick, and something I said is probably not correct. However, what we can assert is this. $P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon \text{ i.o.}) = 0$ for all $\epsilon >0$. Thus $P(\exists \epsilon: |X_n-X|>\epsilon \text{ i.o.}) \leq \sum_{n}P(|X_n-X|>1/n\text{ i.o.}) = 0$.

Comment: @AndrewZhang Are you using this:  $P(\cup A_n)\le \sum P(A_n)$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: The shouldn't it be $\forall \epsilon$ instead of $\exists \epsilon$ ? Otherwise I don't see how  $\{\exists \epsilon: |X_n-X|> \epsilon \text{ i.o.} \}=\cup_n \{  |X_n-X|> 1/n  \text{ i.o.} \}$

Comment: At the very least, the LHS$\subset$ RHS, which is good enough to conclude $X_n\to X$ a.s. To see this inclusion, fix $\omega\in$ LHS. Then I think it’s clear that $\omega \in$ RHS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (1), I think the issue is mainly just notation.  You have successfully shown that the event $(\limsup A_n)^c$, which has probability 1, can be written as
$$\left\{ \exists n_0 \, \forall n \ge n_0  :\, 
\left|\frac{S_n}{n^p}\right| < \epsilon \right\}.$$
The book would write this as
$$\left\{ \exists n_0 : n \ge n_0 \implies |S_n/n^p| < \epsilon\right\}.$$
It is basically just rephrasing "for all $n$ such that $n \ge n_0$ we have XXX" as "for all $n$, if $n \ge n_0$ then we have XXX"; they are logically equivalent.  In fact if you think about it, it is really the *meaning* of  the phrase "such that". They didn't write a quantifier on $n$ but it is assumed to be "for all".

To put it another way, you showed that for every $n \ge n_0$, the statement XXX is true.  So let $\phi$ be the formula $n \ge n_0 \implies XXX$.  We are trying to prove $\forall n : \phi$ so consider two cases.  If $n \ge n_0$ then your argument gives XXX, so statement $\phi$ is true because its consequent is true.  If $n < n_0$ then your argument doesn't give anything, but it doesn't matter because statement $\phi$ is vacuously true in this case (its antecedent is false).

So now the only discrepancy is that you have $< \epsilon$ and they have $\le \epsilon$.  This is really irrelevant for what comes next, but your statement is actually stronger than theirs; i.e. your event is a subset of theirs.  It's basically just the fact that $t < \epsilon$ implies $t \le \epsilon$, and you just have to work through the quantifiers.  Or, use the facts that if $B_n \subset B_n'$ for every $n$, then we have $\bigcap B_n \subset \bigcap B_n'$ and $\bigcup B_n \subset \bigcup B_n'$.

For (2), notice that in your argument above, $\epsilon$ was arbitrary.  So for any $k$, let $B_k = \{ \exists n_0 \, \forall n \ge n_0 \, : |S_n/n^p| \le 1/k\}$.  Taking $\epsilon = 1/k$ in your above argument, you have shown $P(B_k) = 1$, for every $k$.  Let $B = \bigcap_{k \in \mathbb{N}} B_k$; by countable additivity we have $P(B)=1$.  (That is, by de Morgan we have $B = \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} B_k^c$, but since $P(B_k)=1$ we have $P(B_k^c) = 0$, hence $P(B^c) \le \sum_{k=0}^\infty P(B_k^c) = 0$.)  But $B$ is exactly the event in the highlighted equation.

Comment: Thanks Nate, very clear as always.  Would you mind clearing up a couple of things I overlooked?   How does the assumption made at the beginning of the problem ( i.e. $\exists \delta >0 $)such that $E[e^{\theta X}] < \infty$ for $|\theta|\le \delta)$ implies  $E[|X|^k]t^k/k!$ is summable?. All I have from that assumption is that $E[X^k]t^k/k!$ is summable. And second how do I prove that $\exp (-\varepsilon^2n^{2p-1}/4c)$ is summable?. I tried to ask this last thing in a separate question but it got closed and I only received  comments with partial hints that I don't fully understand how to use.

Comment: @some_math_guy: For the first question, monotone convergence says that $$\sum E\left[\frac{|X|^k t^k}{k!}\right] = E\left[\sum \frac{|X|^k t^k}{k!}\right] = E[e^{t|X|}].$$  Now notice the trivial fact that for any real number $x$, we have $e^{t|x|}$ equal to either $e^{tx}$ or $e^{-tx}$, so $e^{t|x|} \le e^{tx} + e^{-tx}$.  Hence $E[e^{t|X|}] \le E[e^{tX}] + E[e^{-tX}]$ which are both finite by assumption.

Comment: @some_math_guy: For the second, one way to go is: since exponentials beat powers, for any $q$ there is $M$ so large that for all $x \ge M$, we have $e^{-\epsilon^2 x/4c} \le x^{-q}$.  Choosing $q$ large enough that $q(2p-1) > 2$ and taking $x = n^{2p-1}$, we have $e^{-\epsilon^2 n^{2p-1}/4c} \le n^{-2}$ for all large enough $n$, which is summable.

Comment: Is the sequence of partial sums the one you are applying monotone convergence to?

Comment: @some_math_guy: Yes.

Comment: Thanks,by the way, I have a similar question 
 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4720734/doubts-on-solution-of-longest-run-of-heads-problem?noredirect=1#comment10000793_4720734   that  has not received much attention. When you 've got some time, I could use some help there.